# How to insert object into Firebase Forge? - AngularFire 0.8.0 - Thinkster - Chapter 7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am following the Thinkster Ang-News tutorial with the latest version of AngularFire (0.8.0) installed. I've managed to get to [part 7](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/4DYrJRxTyT/7-creating-your-own-user-data-using-firebase) of the tutorial successfully but I am stuck on the part where I need to insert a user object into the Firebase Forge. The code works as follows:

When a new user registers via my HTML form, the "register" function is called and "User.create(authUser, $scope.user.username);" is executed within the "register" function.

```
// login and registration page
app.controller('AuthCtrl',
  function ($scope, $location, Auth, User) {

if (Auth.signedIn()) {
  $location.path('/');
}

$scope.$on('firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function(){
    $location.path('/');
});

$scope.login = function(){
    Auth.login($scope.user).then(function(){
        $location.path('/');
    }, function (error){
        $scope.error = error.toString();
    });
};

$scope.register = function () {
  Auth.register($scope.user).then(function (authUser) {
    Auth.login($scope.user);//cause creating user auto login
    User.create(authUser, $scope.user.username);
    console.log(authUser);
    $location.path('/');
}, function (error){
    $scope.error = error.toString(); 
  });
};
 });
```

The "User" service has a function "create" which creates the user object and should store the object information in the Firebase Forge. As you can see below, "users.$save(username)" is called to "$save" the user into the Firebase Forge. However, nothing happens in my Firebase Forge when the $save method is called. I reviewed the latest AngularFire specs, and as you can see in my code comments (//), I tried combining the $asArray(), $asObject() with my "users" variable but that did not work. When I used "users.$add(username);" instead of calling the $save method, my Firebase Forge just added the username without the object's properties.

```
app.factory('User', function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, Auth, $rootScope) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');

 var users = $firebase(ref);
 //var users = $firebase(ref).$asObject();
  //var users = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

  var User = {
create: function (authUser, username) {
  users[username] = {
    md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
    username: username,
    $priority: authUser.uid
  };


    //users.$add(username);

    users.$save(username).then(function () {
        setCurrentUser(username);
    });

}, // end of create fxn
```

Again, I cannot insert the "users[username]" object into my Firebase Forge with the $save or $add AngularFire methods. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Jon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right now you're modifying the binding and then calling `$save`. You have to use `$asObject` or `$asArray` to get to the `$save` method.

In your case though, you don't need to sync any objects—just save one. You can create a new object for the user and use `$update` on the binding.

```
app.factory('User', function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, Auth, $rootScope) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
  var users = $firebase(ref);

  var User = {
    create: function (authUser, username) {

      users.$update(username, {
        md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
        username: username,
        priority: authUser.uid
      });

    }, // end of create fxn
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your explanation. Now, I am able to successfully store user data to my Forge! However, the first time I attempted your solution, I did not work so I checked my console and I learned of this error: "Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument  contains an invalid key ($priority) in property 'phil'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"".......Anyway, I commented out "$priority: authUser.uid" and I was successfully able to create a key and value object in my Forge.

Comment: FYI, I also tested my old code adding "var users = $firebase(ref).$asObject();" and commenting out "$priority: authUser.uid", and I left the $save method and it also successfully create a user object in my Forge. Now, my only issue is fixing the $priority problem.

Comment: David, so I believe I figured it out...After reading [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/iC8gd3LahfY), it appears that whatever is passed in as a key, needs to be a valid JSON object. Therefore, I cannot have "$" in "$priority:authUser.uid". I just used "setPriority: authUser.uid" (from Firebase SDK) and it seems to work. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions. Gracias!

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is deprecated: the `$firebase` service is no longer available in 1.0.0 (possibly sooner?), and `$update` has been silently killed along with it -- not mentioned in any of the release notes :/

For the time being, will have to use the vanilla JS API, or do `$firebaseObject.$loaded().then(function(obj){obj.myUpdates = newData}).$save()` which is extremely inconveneient because you shouldn't have to load the parent object to save a new one.

Comment: @premiumFrye If all you need to do is update data to Firebase, then the JS api makes the most sense. AngularFire is a set services to handle bindings for collections. If you want more information on migrating, there is a section the guide on migrating from 0.9 to 1.0. Which details all of the breaking changes. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/migration-guides.html

Comment: Sure, that's what I was doing and came across this post for and ended up doing: i just wanted to note that `$update` is longer in the API. It wasn't technically 'deprecated', since `$firebaseObject` is new, so it's hard to find any mention of it's removal

Comment: Out of curiosity, did most of your AngularFire information searching come from Stackoverflow posts? Because if so, I could take the time to update a lot of my answers.

Comment: @DavidEast I think a non-insignificant amount, yeah. I feel like angularfire has moved pretty quickly within the past 6 month since I started using it, and unfortunately their docs aren't versioned--it'd be worth it to mention the version the answer is for. For example the above isn't referenced in the release notes or migration path. I also had problems with simple login, since I started using it right when they deprecated the stand-alone library, and before they integrated it with angularfire, so I've experienced lots of friction in their updates

Answer (score 2):

Following on the previous answer, I used this $update syntax to set the priority, which appears to work:

```
users.$update(username, {
    md5_hash : authUser.md5_hash,
    username : username
}).then(function(ref) {
    ref.setPriority(authUser.uid);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

David answered this like a boss already, but for clarity here is the *100% working* code snippet to replace in **/services/user.js**.

```
'use strict';

app.factory('User', function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, Auth, $rootScope) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');

  var users = $firebase(ref);

  var User = {
    create: function (authUser, username) {

      users.$update(username, {
        md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
        username: username,
        setPriority: authUser.uid
      });
    }
  };

  return User;
});
```

Vote David up, not me :).

Comment: Good stuff Andy. Thanks for posting the snippet.