# TypeError: undefined is not a function while submitting & deleting post using AngularFire and AngularJS (ThinksterIO Tutorial Chapter 7)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've run into multiple TypeErrors with the Thinkster.io AngularJS Tutorial: Learn to build Modern Webapps [Chapter 7. Creating your own user data using firebase](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/4DYrJRxTyT/7-creating-your-own-user-data-using-firebase) since the tutorial is now outdated after AngularFire was upgraded to v0.8.0. Specifically the `.$child()` and `.$on()` methods have been taken out. Here is the change log

https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/releases/tag/v0.8.0

After [getting help solving my initial TypeError issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667143/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-with-firebase-and-angularjs-thinksterio) during registering a new user, I began to see 2 new TypeErrors show up when I submit a post and when I try to delete a post. Once again the culprits are the outdated `.$child()` and `.$on()` methods.

### Submitting a Post > TypeError: undefined is not a function

After submitting a post I see the following TypeError show up in the console

[image]

This TypeError points to the `post.js` service

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/post.js:16:11
```

which is line 16, column 11 at the beginning of the `$child` method call. Also, note the second `.&child()` following the first. That will result in another TypeError.

```
return posts.$add(post).then(function(ref) {
  var postId = ref.name();
  user.$child('posts').$child(postId).$set(postId);
  return postId;
});
```

I will mention that even though I get this TypeError, I'm still able to successfully create a post and I see it in the Forge and in the app's post list.

### Deleting a Post > TypeError: undefined is not a function

When I try to delete a post that I just created I get another TypeError related to the now deprecated `.$on()` method.

[image]

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.Post [as delete] (http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/post.js:27:10)
    at Scope.$scope.deletePost (http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/posts.js:10:14)
```

which points to the `.$on()` in this code in the **post.js** service

```
delete: function(postId) {
  if(User.signedIn()) {
    var post = Post.find(postId);
    post.$on('loaded', function(){
      var user = User.findByUsername(post.owner);
      posts.$remove(postId).then(function(){
        user.$child('posts').$remove(postId);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

I realize that I will have to do something like

```
post.$loaded(function(result) {Chapter 7. Creating your own user data using firebase
  // something related to finding user of post
  // remove post from posts collection 
  // but of course we can't use .$child()
});
```

but the problem is that when a JS beginner like me comes along faced with the AngularFire change logs and API, I just get lost and overwhelmed to the point of shut down. Any guidance is greatly appreciated as always.

---

### FILES

---

**post.js** service

```
'use strict';

app.factory('Post', function($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, User){
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'posts');
  var posts = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

  var Post = {
    all: posts,
    create: function(post) {
      if(User.signedIn()) {
        var user = User.getCurrent();
        post.owner = user.username;

        return posts.$add(post).then(function(ref) {
          var postId = ref.name();
          user.$child('posts').$child(postId).$set(postId);
          return postId;
        });
      }
    },
    find: function(postId) {
            return $firebase(ref.child(postId)).$asObject();
    },
    delete: function(postId) {
      if(User.signedIn()) {
        var post = Post.find(postId);
        post.$on('loaded', function(){
          var user = User.findByUsername(post.owner);
          posts.$remove(postId).then(function(){
            user.$child('posts').$remove(postId);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };

  return Post;

});
```

---

**post.js** controller

```
'use strict';

app.controller('PostsCtrl', function($scope, $location, Post) {

  $scope.posts = Post.all;

  $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};

  $scope.deletePost = function(post) {
    Post.delete(post);
  };

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert object into Firebase Forge? - AngularFire 0.8.0 - Thinkster - Chapter 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319523/how-to-insert-object-into-firebase-forge-angularfire-0-8-0-thinkster-chap)

Comment: The Thinkster tutorial is currently out of date with the latest version of AngularFire. The 0.8 update of AngularFire came with a couple of new sync methods ($asObject and $asArray) while removing $child and $on. See the docs for more details. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html

Answer (score 1):

I was fed up, so I took a easy approach (just to get trough the tutorial). I created userRef (this should come from the User object imo):

```
modulename.factory("Post", function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, User) {
    //rest code

    var userRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "users");

    var Post = {
        create: function(){
            //rest of the code

            return posts.$add(post).then(function (ref) {
                var postId = ref.name();

                userRef.child(user.$id).child("posts").child(postId).set(postId);

                return postId;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This is just one approach, when I was searching for a good solution, I saw some more example codes. I hope it helps a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for that but this past week the ThinksterIO team launched a revised version of the tutorial that almost works. I'm not sure if you are interested in going back over it but if you do you might hit a problem with the `Post.delete()` function code in the **post.js** factory. I documented it here in a new SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788083/post-deletepost-function-not-working-in-revised-thinksterio-learn-to-build-rea